# Removing one level/group from Facet_wrap ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, facet-wrap

My tbl_df:

```
> str(p2p_dt_SKILL_A)
Classes ‘tbl_dt’, ‘tbl’, ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 693 obs. of  35 variables:
 $ Patch          : Factor w/ 7 levels "BVG1","BVG11",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 ...
 $ Skill          : Factor w/ 15 levels "A","BROADBAND",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Date           : Date, format: "2015-12-04" "2015-12-04" "2015-12-04" "2015-12-04" ...
 $ SOD_FWIH_A     : num  1.09 1.14 1.09 1.1 1.09 1.07 1.09 1.07 1.12 1.07 ...
 $ Prod_MWF       : num  5.06 5.06 5.44 5.34 4.22 4.72 4.89 4.68 4.68 5.22 ...
 $ Prod_MA        : num  4.41 4.41 4.81 4.41 4.68 4.15 4.26 4.44 4.44 4.63 ...
 $ Prod_DL        : num  3.43 3.49 3.45 3.57 3.43 3.47 3.28 3.44 3.42 3.72 ...
```

created the following line plot using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(p2p_dt_SKILL_A,aes(x=Date,y=Prod_DL)) +
        geom_line(data = p2p_dt_SKILL_A[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Patch %in% c("BVG1"),],aes(colour="red"),lwd=1.3) +
        geom_smooth() +
        scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%y"),breaks ="1 month")+
        geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date=="2015-09-18"]))+
        geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date=="2015-10-02"]))+
        geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date=="2015-10-23"]))+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15,face="bold",color="red"),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 15,lineheight = .8,face="bold",color="red"),
              axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Now I am trying to use `facet_wrap` but without the `"BVG1" Patch`. But facet_wrap picks up the BVG1 patch as well:

```
ggplot(p2p_dt_SKILL_A,aes(x=Date,y=Prod_DL)) +
        geom_line(data = p2p_dt_SKILL_A[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Patch != "BVG1",],aes(colour="red"),lwd=1.3) +
        scale_colour_discrete(drop = FALSE)+
        geom_smooth() +
        geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean")+
        scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%y"),breaks ="2 month")+
        geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date=="2015-09-18"]))+

         geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date=="2015-10-02"]))+
         geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date[p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date=="2015-10-23"]))+
        ylab("DL Prod for All Skills")+
        ggtitle("BVG1 DL Prod for All Skills 2014-2015")+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15,face="bold",color="red"),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 15,lineheight = .8,face="bold",color="red"),
              axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              legend.position="none")+
        facet_wrap(~Patch, ncol = 3)
```

[image]

How to get `facet_wrap` to just print from `BVG11` to `BVG16` and exclude `BVG1` group?

I tried using a new dataframe excluding BVG1 but it doesn't print nicely and lines are all over the place like:

```
som_data <- p2p_dt %>%
                        filter(Patch != "BVG1" & Skill %in% c("A"))

> str(som_data)
Classes ‘tbl_dt’, ‘tbl’, ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 594 obs. of  39 variables:
 $ Patch          : Factor w/ 6 levels "BVG11","BVG12",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ Skill          : Factor w/ 1 level "A": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Date           : Date, format: "2015-12-04" "2015-11-27" "2015-11-20" "2015-11-13" ...
 $ SOD_FWIH_A     : num  1.14 1.12 1.15 1.09 1.13 1.14 1.15 1.16 1.14 1.11 ...
 $ Prod_MWF       : num  5.06 4.68 4.69 4.76 4.63 4.98 4.45 5.12 4.44 4.54 ...
 $ Prod_MA        : num  4.41 4.44 4.14 5.63 4.86 4.97 4.65 4.99 4.52 4.9 ...
 $ Prod_DL        : num  3.49 3.42 3.6 3.29 3.19 3.1 3.18 3.28 3.26 3.21 ...
```

using newly created dataframe above, it creates the following graph and means are also not correct

```
ggplot(som_data,aes(x=Date,y=Prod_DL)) +
        geom_line(aes(colour="red"),lwd=1.3) +
        geom_smooth() +
        geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean")+
        scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%y"),breaks ="2 month")+
        geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(som_data$Date[som_data$Date=="2015-09-18"]))+
        geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(som_data$Date[som_data$Date=="2015-10-02"]))+
        geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(som_data$Date[som_data$Date=="2015-10-23"]))+
        ylab("DL Prod for All Skills")+
        ggtitle("BVG1 SOMs DL Prod for All Skills 2014-2015")+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15,face="bold",color="red"),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 15,lineheight = .8,face="bold",color="red"),
              axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              legend.position="none")+
        facet_wrap(~Patch)
```

[image]

any ideas???

Comment: Perhaps you can use `?droplevels`

Comment: Why not use `som_data <- p2p_dt_SKILL_A %>% filter(Patch !=  "BVG1")`  and then perhaps `p2p_dt_SKILL_A <- droplevels(p2p_dt_SKILL_A)`.

Comment: in your first data set Skill has 15 levels in your second, it has only 1 level

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I have dropped the levels and It has only one skill and remaining Patches (I assure you that) but still no luck

Comment: `> som_data$Skill Levels: A` `> som_data$Patch Levels: BVG11 BVG12 BVG13 BVG14 BVG15 BVG16`

Comment: The first dataframe is also filtered on `Skill=="A"`

Comment: Seems like a question about filtering and levels. If you want this sorted out, you'll probably have to share some example data for us to play with.

Comment: @Axeman updated answer with `dput`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see where the problem is. Here is a minimal example with the data you provided.

```
library(dplyr)
# I first need to get rid of the data.table
sample_data <- as.data.frame(sample_data)
# I don't want all those other variables you gave me either..
sample_data <- select(sample_data, Date, Prod_DL, Patch)

# Now filter out the Patch that we don't want
sample_data2 <- filter(sample_data, Patch != "BVG1")

# Create a minimal plot
ggplot(sample_data2, aes(x = Date, y = Prod_DL)) +
  geom_line(colour="red", lwd = 1.3) +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~Patch, ncol = 3)
```

Not exactly a great plot (there is limited data) but only six panels.

[image]

Comment: its funny but I have resolved the issue. I didn't do anything particular just rerun the command and it worked! but thanks for your effort any way :)

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example next time so you can catch any mistakes.